How to do a GDPR Cookie consent banner on Carrd?
I've previously done this on Webflow, there was a cookie consent banner, if someone opted in the Facebook pixel would trigger to register a pageview.
Last week I moved my new site to Carrd, can't find any documentation on how to do it on their platform.
Has anyone done this on Carrd?  If so, could you please show me how to do it or signpost me to the documentation.
Many thanks
Jayne
Haven't tried doing anything at the moment.
